# Is there an way to import an nx-library module in another nx-library module?

Tags: javascript, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

My project is based on nx-workpsace and i am having 1 project in `apps` and 2 libraries in my `libs` folder.

The structure looks like this:

```
+-- apps
|   +-- main-application
+-- libs
|   +-- lib-1 (feature-library)
|   +-- lib-2 (shared-components-library)
```

I am importing the `lib-1` in my `main-application` like this:

```
imports: [
  lib1Module.forRoot()
]
```

If i now try to import the `lib1Module` in my `lib2Module` like this

```
imports: [
  lib1Module
]
```

Im getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lib1Module')`

I think the error is the `forRoot()` in the main application but i don't know how to fix this, because i need to provide the `lib-1` services in the `main-application`. The reason why i need the `lib1Module` in my `lib2Module` is that i use an `directive` of `lib-1` in `lib-2`.

**Info**

If I remove the `forRoot()` it still doesnt work. Is there a way to import an module in an `nx-library` from another `nx-library`?